# powershell, leading zero trimed from [string[]] parameters when there is 2+ values

Tags: powershell

I have a cmdlet which accepts a list of phone numbers as a parameter. some phone numbers have 0 as first character. when I call the function with exactly one number, the string is kept as is. when I call the function with 2+ numbers, the leading zero are trimmed

```
function user {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(mandatory,position=0)]
        [string[]]
        $numbers
    )

    process {

        $numbers
        $users = @{
            '0600000001' = 'user1'
            '0600000002' = 'user2'
        }

        foreach($key in $users.keys) {
            if($numbers -contains $key) {
                write-host $users[$key]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for example,

```
[PS] D:\> user 0600000001
0600000001
user1

[PS] D:\> user 0600000002
0600000002
user2
```

but

```
[PS] D:> user 0600000001,0600000002
600000001
600000002
```

of course, if I add quotes around the numbers, it works as expected

```
[PS] D:\> user '0600000001','0600000002'
0600000001
0600000002
user2
user1
```

but the cmdlet is not for my usage and users are very keen on forgetting to put quotes around parameters.

I googled a bit, found many posts/articles on PS mangling strings with leading zero but found no solution on how to prevent it.

do you have any clue?

### edit

the real cmdlet has a pattern verification on the phone numbers and the leading zero being trimmed breaks the verification

```
function user {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(mandatory,position=0)]
        [ValidatePattern('^(\+33|0[67])\d{8}|\+(?!33)\d+$')]
        [string[]]
        $numbers
    )
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: I would make it accepting only one number at a time and repeat calling it as often as needed. ‍♂️

Comment: Sadly, this is somewhat down to the way PowerShell treats and casts arguments. You could sort of get around it by adding `ValueFromRemainingArguments` to the parameter and removing the commas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider the behavior you've observed **a *bug***, which has since been reported in [GitHub issue #20717](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20717):

- With a ***scalar* argument (a single value)** in [argument (parsing) mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#argument-mode), when PowerShell's parameter binder initiallly parses something that it *can* parse *as a number literal*, it does so, i.e. **converts the argument to a *number type* such as `[int]` while *also preserving the original string representation*** in case the target command is ultimtately *not* expecting a number.

  - Examples include `0600000001`, `2.3`, `0xA`, `1e2` and even `1l` or `1d` (number-type suffixes)

    - Unlike in [expression mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#expression-mode), however, a token that starts with `+` or `-` is *not* parsed as a number and remains a *string* (`[string]`).
  - This behavior is implemented by wrapping the resulting *number* instance (e.g. of type `[int]`) in an *invisible `[psobject]` wrapper* that caches the original string representation; the latter can be retrieved by calling `.psobject.ToString()` - but *not* with `.ToString()` and *not* via string interpolation in expandable strings (`"..."`)
  - `.psobject.ToString()` is *implicitly* called in the following scenarios:

    - When calling *external programs*, because it is important to pass the *original* string representation, because there is no concept of *types* in that context, and converting an original argument such as `0xA` into `10` wouldn't be appropriate.
    - During default for-display formatting.
    - When casting to `[string]`
- In an ***array* argument, this original string representation is unexpectedly *lost*** for its *elements*, even though there's no good reason *not* to perform the same wrapping on each element (which is technically possible, given that PowerShell arrays are `[object[]]`-typed, i.e. its elements can store values of *any type*).

  - Note that in your `user 0600000001,0600000002` call, `0600000001,0600000002` is *not* parsed in *expression (parsing) mode* - it is still parsed in *argument mode*, in which `,` is *also* supported for array construction (except when calling *external programs*, where no concept of an array exists), with the *elements* parsed the same way *individual* argument-mode arguments are.
  - For instance, `Write-Output foo, bar` is the all-argument-mode equivalent of
    `Write-Output ('foo', 'bar')`, i.e. argument mode statement with a *nested expression*.

To **demonstrate the problem** succinctly:

```
& {
  param($Value) # implicitly [object]-typed - see below for why
  foreach ($v in $Value) { 
    [pscustomobject] @{
      StringRepresentation = $v.ToString()
      OriginalStringRepresentation = $v.psobject.ToString()
      Type = $v.GetType()
      IsPSObjectWrapped = $Value -is [psobject]
    }
 }
} 042
```

This outputs the following, showing that argument `042` was parsed as `[int]` with value `42`, but wrapped in a `[psobject]` instance with the cached original string representation:

```
StringRepresentation OriginalStringRepresentation Type         IsPSObjectWrapped
-------------------- ---------------------------- ----         -----------------
42                   042                          System.Int32              True
```

Transitioning to an *array* of such arguments shows that this wrapping is *lost*:
Passing `042, 043, +44, -45` instead of `042` yields:

```
StringRepresentation OriginalStringRepresentation Type          IsPSObjectWrapped
-------------------- ---------------------------- ----          -----------------
42                   42                           System.Int32              False
43                   43                           System.Int32              False
+44                  +44                          System.String             False
-45                  -45                          System.String             False
```

Note how the original string representation of `042` and `043` was lost, whereas `+44` and `-45` - due to their prefix - were parsed as *strings* to begin with.

Note:

- The sample script block uses an *untyped*, i.e. implicitly `[object]`-typed parameter, which enables examining the behavior without explicit type conversions.

  - If the parameter had been declared as `[object[]]` (aka `[Array]`), the original string representation is lost even in the *single*-argument case, which could be considered a bug in its own right.
- With a `[string[]]`-typed parameter, as demonstrated in your question, it does work for the *single*-argument case, but fails in the multi-argument case, because the original string representation is already lost by the time the `[string[]]` array is constructed, because the loss occurs during the initial, behind-the scenes, of necessity `[object]`-based array parsing.

Comment: I tested the cmdlet in its original ecosystem (PS v2) and the bug is not present. in v4 and v5.1 it's present. so more than a bug, it's a regression :(

Comment: I see, @Peyre. While my sense is that this won't get fixed anytime soon, it helps if you - and anyone else interested in seeing this fixed - give the linked GitHub issue a thumbs-up.

Comment: I wanted to contribute to the GitHub with an example like the one in the edit I added to this post but I have no PS > 5.1 handy to test if this also happens in the last version. does the ValidatePattern also throw an error in PS v7.x ?

Comment: @Peyre, yes, it also fails the validation in PS v7+ (the values seen by `[ValidatePattern()]` have already been stripped of their original string representation).